# Python: Variable Right n Characters

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, character

I'm trying to return the right n characters based on how many characters are right of a specific character.  In this case it is the "#" sign.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(kitties)
df.columns = ['Asset','Endtime','Price']
df['neg_one'] = -1
df['pos_one'] = 1
df['Asset_num_1']= df['Asset'].str[-5:]
df['Asset_num_2'] = df['Asset_num_1'].str.find(search_value)
df['Asset_num_3'] = df['Asset_num_2'] + df['pos_one']
df['Asset_num_4']= df['Asset'].str[(df['Asset_num_3']*df['neg_one']):]
```

Everything looks like its working except the last line where I'm trying to set the number of characters to return by using a formula.

Gives me the below dataset:

34  Kitty #5090 2021-12-23 22:00:00+00:00   419       -1        1       #5090            0            1          NaN
35  Kitty #577 2021-12-23 10:00:00+00:00   427       -1        1        #577            1            2          NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For filter charaters by another columns use:

```
df['Asset_num_4']= df.apply(lambda x: x['Asset'][x['Asset_num_3']*x['neg_one']:], axis=1)
```

Or list comprehension:

```
df['Asset_num_4']= [a[b*c:] for a,b,c in df[['Asset','Asset_num_3','neg_one']].to_numpy()]
```

Comment: Thank you!  I realized I needed to change the value I was using in that line, but ultimately settled on this:

    df['Asset_num_4']= df.apply(lambda x: x['Asset_num_1'][((len(x['Asset_num_1'])-x['Asset_num_3'])*x['neg_one']):], axis=1)